# Sorting list by multiple methods

Tags: python, sorting, methods

I have a list of flights, which are to be sorted on departure date first, and then to be sorted on the total flight duration, keeping their order according to the date.

- Calling the departure date is a method of the "Flight" object.
- Calling the flight duration is also a method of the "Flight" object.

output should be:

- 04-07-2017 flighttime: 05:00
- 04-07-2017 flighttime: 06:00
- 05-07-2017 flighttime: 04:00
- 05-07-2017 flighttime: 05:00

I tried:

```
sorted(flights, key=methodcaller('date','flighttime'))
```

but methodcaller only takes 1 argument. I tried also groupby first and then sort on flighttime, but then the list gets sorted to flighttime only.

thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`methodcaller` cannot call more than 1 method, the other arguments are parameters:

> f = methodcaller('name', 'foo', bar=1), the call f(b) returns b.name('foo', bar=1)

So it can be done using `methodcaller` but in a more complex way probably involving `lambda` like (untested) `lambda x : methodcaller('name')(x),methodcaller('flighttime')(x)`

So I would use a simple `lambda` instead (where `x` is a `Flight` object):

```
sorted(flights, key=lambda x : (x.date(),x.flighttime()))
```

Comment: Thanks! And if I want to maintain the date order, but reverse the flighttime order? Thus only reversing on the second key?

Comment: if flightime is numerical, you can just inverse the second key: `sorted(flights, key=lambda x : (x.date(),-x.flighttime()))`

Comment: No it is a timedelta, but it worked by putting the - in front! Thanks

Comment: ah timedelta is smart. Good.